# How to implement 2D vector array?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm using the vector class in the STL library for the first time. How should I add to a specific row of the vector array?

```
struct x{
     vector <vector <int> > v;
     int row;
 };

vector< int* > my ints;
int add;
```

if i wanted to add to first row of v with the first pointer of integers, could I do

```
myints[0]->v[myints[0]->row].push_back(add);
```

Is this method fine to create a 2 D vector of vector `int`s where each row could potentially be of different length (i.e. have a different number of columns)?

Comment: That famous Standard Template Library Library

Comment: `vector< int* > my ints;` is not valid C++. Let's try this question again, with a compilable testcase that reproduces the problem.

Comment: `myints[0]` is `int*`. What the heck is `myints[0]->v`  ?

Answer (score 76):

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, as your example code has several errors and doesn't really make it clear what you're trying to do. But here's how you add to a specific row of a 2D vector:

```
// declare 2D vector
vector< vector<int> > myVector;
// make new row (arbitrary example)
vector<int> myRow(1,5);
myVector.push_back(myRow);
// add element to row
myVector[0].push_back(1);
```

Does this answer your question? If not, could you try to be more specific as to what you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 60):

If you know the (maximum) number of rows and columns beforehand, you can use [`resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) to initialize a vector of vectors and then modify (and access) elements with [`operator[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/). Example:

```
int no_of_cols = 5;
int no_of_rows = 10;
int initial_value = 0;

std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;
matrix.resize(no_of_rows, std::vector<int>(no_of_cols, initial_value));

// Read from matrix.
int value = matrix[1][2];

// Save to matrix.
matrix[3][1] = 5;
```

Another possibility is to use just one vector and split the id in several variables, access like `vector[(row * columns) + column]`.

Answer (score 18):

Just use the following methods to create a 2-D vector.

```
int rows, columns;        

// . . .

vector < vector < int > > Matrix(rows, vector< int >(columns,0));
```

OR

```
vector < vector < int > > Matrix;

Matrix.assign(rows, vector < int >(columns, 0));

//Do your stuff here...
```

This will create a Matrix of size **rows * columns** and initializes it with **zeros** because we are passing a zero(0) as a second argument in the constructor i.e **vector < int > (columns, 0)**.

Comment: If you know the exact number of columns in advance, or even a reasonably small maximum value, you probably want to use `std::vector< std::array<int> >`.  If you know the exact number of rows as well, `std::array< std::array <int> >`.

Answer (score 12):

> //initialize the 2D vector first

`vector<vector<int>> matrix;`

> //initialize the 1D vector you would like to insert into matrix

`vector<int> row;`

> //initializing row with values

`row.push_back(val1);`

`row.push_back(val2);`

> //now inserting values into matrix

`matrix.push_back(row);`

> //output-
>   [[val1,val2]]

Answer (score 8):

We can easily use vector as 2d array. We use resize() method for this purpose.
The code below can be helpful to understand this issue.

### Code Snippet :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int row, col;
    cin>>row>>col;

    vector <vector<int>> v;
    v.resize(col,vector<int>(row));

    //v = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}}; 

    /** input from use **/
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
       for(int j=0; j<col; j++)
       {
          cin>>v[i][j];
       }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<row; i++)
    {
       for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
       {
          cout<<v[i][j]<<" ";
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to define a 2-d vector is to declare a vector of pair's.

```
 vector < pair<int,int> > v;

**To insert values**
 cin >> x >>y;
 v.push_back(make_pair(x,y));

**Retrieve Values**
 i=0 to size(v)
 x=v[i].first;
 y=v[i].second;
```

For 3-d vectors take a look at tuple and make_tuple.

Comment: That's not 2D, that's 1.5d. One of the dimension is hard-coded to be size 2.

Answer (score 2):

I use this piece of code . works fine for me .copy it and run on your computer. you'll understand by yourself .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector <vector <int> > matrix;
    size_t row=3 , col=3 ;
    for(int i=0,cnt=1 ; i<row ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0 ; j<col ; j++)
        {
            vector <int> colVector ;
            matrix.push_back(colVector) ;
            matrix.at(i).push_back(cnt++) ;
        }
    }
    matrix.at(1).at(1) = 0;     //matrix.at(columns).at(rows) = intValue 
    //printing all elements
    for(int i=0,cnt=1 ; i<row ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0 ; j<col ; j++)
        {
            cout<<matrix[i][j] <<" " ;
        }
        cout<<endl ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**vector<vector> matrix(row, vector(col, 0));**

This will initialize a 2D vector of **rows=row** and **columns = col** with all initial values as 0. No need to initialize and use resize.

Since the vector is initialized with size, you can use "**[]**" operator as in array to modify the vector.

**matrix[x][y] = 2;**

Answer (score 1):

`vector<int> adj[n];` // where n is number of rows in 2d vector.