# Made a 2D array with properties from a class, having troubles changing the values

Tags: c++, arrays, class, 2d

So basically I made a 2-D array, `Component pixel[][]`, with `Component` being the class and I am trying to change one of the variables for the grid (being made from the value of dimension). For some reason, when I run the code mostly all of it prints out `0`'s and `1`'s except for one of them.

```
class Component {
public:
    int label;
    int order;
};

int main() {
    int dimension;
    float density;
    float R;

    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter a grid size between 5 and 15: ";
        cin >> dimension;
        if(dimension > 15 || dimension < 5)
        {
            cout << "Needs to be between 5 and 15" << endl;
        }
    }while(dimension > 15 || dimension < 5);

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a density value between 0.0 and 1.0: ";
        cin >> density;
        if(density > 1.0 || density < 0.0)
        {
            cout << "Needs to be between 0.0 and 1.0" << endl;
        }
    }while(density > 1.0 || density < 0.0);

    Component pixel[dimension][dimension];

    srand (unsigned(time(NULL)));
    for (int row = 1; row <= dimension; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= dimension; col++)
        {
            R = (float)rand()/(RAND_MAX+1);
            cout << R << " ";
            if (R < density)
            {
                pixel[row][col].label = 1;
            }
            else
                pixel[row][col].label = 0;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int row = 1; row <= dimension; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= dimension; col++)
        {
            cout << pixel[row][col].label << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?  VLAs are not part of C++.  Also, you need to understand that arrays are 0-based, not 1-based.

Answer (score 0):

As seen from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31090156/3349368 , try using STL `std::vector<std::vector<Component> >` instead.

From the above link,

```
int no_of_cols = 5;
int no_of_rows = 10;
int initial_value = 0;

std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;
matrix.resize(no_of_rows, std::vector<int>(no_of_cols, initial_value));

// Read from matrix.
int value = matrix[1][2];

// Save to matrix.
matrix[3][1] = 5;
```

Just replace `int` with `Component`

Answer (score 0):

As I learned the hard way, array sizes must be known at compile time.  You're not allowed to cin >> array sizes and set them during run time.  They have to be const int, declared explicitly in the code.  As stated above, if you want to be able to change their size at run time, use the std::vector instead since they are dynamic, not static.