# C++ (Or any other language) Is it possible to read data from a file into a matrix where the number of dimensions is unknown at compile time?

Tags: data-structures

The title of this question concisely sums up what it is I want to ask, but I shall add some more details and context below.

## Context

I am doing some work with "image files". These images files, broadly speaking, can be either 2d, or 3d, or possibly 4d, although I am yet to encounter an example with the work I am doing.

Obviously 3d and 4d images probably seem a bit strange. I am not working with images in the traditional sense of JPG or PNG pictures, but images which describe spatial mathematical data for use in AI and machine learning.

## File Format

The file format I am using is very general and very flexible. It is designed to hold arbitrary numbers of matrices, of arbitrary dimension, with arbitrary numbers of dimensions... Probably seems a bit abstract so let us focus on an example case.

So far I have been working with, for example, 2d images of digits. In this case, the file format is as follows:

- First there is a 4 byte integer which contains the number of matrix objects in the file.
- Next there is another 4 byte integer which contains the number of dimensions of the first matrix object stored in the file.
- To make this example concrete, let us assume there is 1 object in the file, so the first 4 byte integer is 1.
- Let us also assume we are working with a 2d image, so the next 4 byte integer is "2", as the image has data in 2 dimensions.
- Moving on, the 3rd 4 byte integer is the length of the first dimension, and the 4th 4 byte integer is the length of the second dimension. (We know the matrix has 2 dimensions, so we know to read 2 x 4 byte integers to know how much storage is required to allocate memory for the data.
- Then we must read the data. Assuming the format is of type `double`, and assuming our images are 100 x 100 in size, we must read 80000 bytes of data into 10000 doubles until we get to the next object in the file. (The format then repeats, so we read a 4 byte integer to find out how many dimensions the next object has.)

I hope that is clear.

## Example so-called "Flat" Storage Allocation

Let's say we choose to allocate our memory using a `std::vector`. (For other programming languages, assume some sort of dynamic array.) We can allocate enough memory by reading the number of dimensions, `N`, and reading `N` integers into another array, and multiplying all those integers together to find the total number of elements required to be allocated. (This would be a "flat" or "linear" storage allocation.) Hopefully that all makes sense.

***What I actually want to achieve (Not "flat" allocation)***

However, the flat allocation isn't very convenient. It would be preferable to read a 2d object into a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`, and a 3d object into the 3d version of this. (`std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>`)

However I think it may be impossible to write such a program as the number of dimensions is not known at compile time!

***Simplified Problem***

It would be possible to assume the maximum number of possible dimensions we will encounter is 4, and store all objects as `vector<vector<vector<vector<double>>>>`, and throw an error if we ever found a file containing an object with dimension 5.

***General Problem***

But what if the dimension truly is completely arbitrary, and we frequently encounter values larger than 4? Is it possible to write an object which behaves as an object with arbitrary numbers of indices?

Perhaps this is the wrong question to ask, and a better one is, considering this file format, how does one approach the problem of reading data into memory? (Not using the flat model I described.)

## Appended Notes

I believe this problem is not too dissimilar to the problem of evaluating a mathematical expression read from an input stream / file, **or** alternatively, it is not too dissimilar from the problem of writing a language compiler, specifically an interpreted language compiler. The reason I say this, is that in this case, we must read some data from the file before we know what it is we are actually doing. [What does the matrix look like? How many dimensions does it have and what size are those dimensions?] (I can't really put into words my thoughts here in a more clear way. I hope you can follow what I'm thinking here. I think the solution may be possible taking inspiration from the way in which language interpreters (mathematical expression / matlab / python / script etc) work, however I don't know anything about this.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement 2D vector array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694838/how-to-implement-2d-vector-array)

Comment: @TheBlackCat No. This question is in no way related to that one as far as I can see.

Comment: @TheBlackCat In addition - that question doesn't have an answer or even appear to make sense.

Comment: Why is the flat allocation inconvenient? Just because referencing it is inconvenient (i.e. you can't use `foo[a][b][c][d]`)? Or do you actually need a `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>` so that you can replace, say, an entire dimension at one go?

Comment: @JimMischel A good question, thanks - yes it is primarily the former, however the later may also be useful (but not in the context I am working with right now)

Comment: Well, you could code up a class that treats the "flat model" one-dimensional array as an n-dimensional array that does the math to figure out the flat index offset represented by the multiple dimensions. But if you want to support varying dimensions then you either need multiple classes or use a single class with accessor functions that will take a variable number of parameters. The result would be kind of slow, though, because every access is a function call and you likely wouldn't get the benefit of compiler optimization within loops.

Comment: @JimMischel I have a vague idea about what you're describing here - is there any chance you could add some examples to make it clearer?

Comment: You might also be interested in https://www.cs.upc.edu/~jordicf/Teaching/programming/pdf/IP10_Matrices.pdf

Comment: @user3728501: You are right, sorry.  Somehow I misread "where the number of dimensions is unknown" as "where the dimensions is unknown".

Comment: @TheBlackCat Okay can you remove your duplicate tag? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You asked for some examples to explain my comment.

(My C++ is rusty, so if my syntax is a bit off, please forgive. If there's something that's so wonky that you can't figure it out, I'm happy to clarify.)

The memory for a multi-dimensional array is allocated as a single contiguous block. That is, `double foo[5][10];` is allocated as a single block of 50 doubles, or 200 bytes. The first 10 values are for row 0, the next 10 for row 1, etc.

When you access the array, `double bar = foo[y][x]`, the compiler generates code to convert your two-dimensional index into a one-dimensional index. Something like: `index = (10*y) + x;` So `foo[3][8]` would correspond to index 38. And `foo[4,9]` would be index 49--the last of the 50 bytes. (Gotta love zero-based indexing, but it makes talking about things difficult.)

So you could write your own two-dimensional array class where you pass the constructor the dimensions and the data (assuming you've already read it into a flat array), and provide accessor functions. Again, my C++ is rusty.

```
public int XSize;
public int YSize;
public double[] Data;

constructor Array2D(int xDim, int yDim, double[] data)
{
    XSize = xDim;
    YSize = yDim;
    Data = data;
}

int DataIndex(int y, int x)
{
    // You could do array bounds checking here if you like.
    return (y * XSize) + x;
}
```

And in your code you load the data and construct one of these things:

```
// assume you've loaded the dimensions xDim and yDim
int sizeBytes = xDim * yDim * sizeof(double);

// I forgot how to allocate memory in C++. It's been a while.
double *data = new double[sizeBytes];

// create your Array2D
Array2D myArray = new Array2D(xDim, yDim, data);
```

So, now you have your array and you want to access the element at [3][8]:

```
double bar = myArray.Data[myArray.DataIndex(y, x)];
```

Granted, it's kind of inconvenient to type. In C# I can create an indexer so that it would look like a normal array access. I suspect somebody who's more conversant with C++ could do the same.

Assuming you can get over the syntactic hurdle, the difficulty is writing the code to work with multiple types. That is, when you start reading the file you don't know what you're returning. Does the array have one dimension or four? You'd need code that reads the number of dimensions and then branches to return an `Array1D` or `Array2D` or `Array3D`, etc.

If that works for you, then great.

You could also create a single multi-dimensional array class. Your constructor would then take the data pointer, count of dimensions, and an array of dimension sizes. The problem, though, is that your `DataIndex` function then has to take a variable number of arguments, and you'll have to do parameter checking to ensure that the correct number of parameters is passed, and throw an error if not.

It's doable, but messing with the variadic functions is going to cause you pain.

And all of this is going to incur a big performance hit. Consider this simple loop over a 2D array:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 5; Y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        DoSomething(foo[y][x]);
    }
}
```

The compiler can optimize that loop. Rather than computing the `y` offset at every iteration of the inner loop, it can compute it only when `y` changes, and then just add the `x` parameter to it. So instead of:

```
for y = 0 to 5
    for x = 0 to 10
        index = 10*y + x
```

It becomes

```
for y = 0 to 5
    yOffset = 10*y
    for x = 0 to 10
        index = yOffset + x
```

You can imagine that computing the index can get expensive in a hurry as the number of dimensions increases.

The general idea of treating a flat array as an array with multiple dimensions isn't new. That's how languages have worked for decades. But creating a general purpose multidimensional array class that lets you specify dimensions dynamically is a bit more difficult.

Comment: Thanks for this - I guess the problem is I have to write a class for each new number of dimensions I may encounter - as you have pointed out here. By the way did you mean `index = yOffset + x` in your last line of code?

Comment: By the way I made a small edit - see the line where you allocate memory. (Changed it to correct C++ syntax)