# How to declare and initialize a 2d array of specific-sized vectors?

Tags: c++

For a single vector we simply do the following:

```
vector<T> v(size);
```

However, when making a 2d array, this logical extension of the syntax doesn't work:

```
vector<T> v(size)[N][N];
```

How to make this work, and why doesn't C++ work this way?

Comment: Do you want a 2D array of T or a 2D array of vector<T>?

Comment: " this logical extension of the syntax doesn't work" I'd disagree honestly. It doesn't work because a `vector` is a 1D building block. You set the element of a vector to be another vector with some other element type. `vector<vector <T>> v(size);` and to access an element `v[x][y];`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement 2D vector array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694838/how-to-implement-2d-vector-array)

Comment: It doesn't work that way, because a vector is an object with a constructor that emulates a resizable array, but is not actually an array.    You can create a `std::vector<std::vector<T> >`  via `std::vector<std::vector<T> > v(N, std::vector<T>(size))` to emulate a 1D array of vectors, and a `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T> > >` via via `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T> >) v(N, std::vector<std::vector<T> >(N, std::vector<T>(size)))` to emulate a 2D array of vectors.

Comment: @George `vector<vector <T>> v(size);` doesn't create a N by N array, but a N by 0. `vector<vector<T>> v(N, vector<T>(N))` would create a N by N array.

Comment: Maybe it will be easier for you to use `vector<vector<T>> v(N*N, vector<T>(size));`  . Otherwise you'll have to use a loop to resize every vector in the array (or a pile of constexpr hackery)

Comment: @M.M but this would create a N² by N array, wouldn't it? Did you mean `vector<T> v(N*N)` to create a flattened array?

Comment: @Timo No I didn't mean that. I'm assuming for now that OP wants what they actually said (i.e. a 3-d array) but awaiting their clarification

Answer (score 2):

Vector allocates memory dynamically so you dont need to specify the size of vector in advance.
You can simply declare vectors as

```
vector<vector<int>>v;
```

If you want to initialize it with some predefined values like 0 or something else then

```
   vector<vector<int> >vect(row);  

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) { 
        vect[i] = vector<int>(col); 
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) 
            vect[i][j] = j + 1; 
    }
```

Or simply this will do if you know all the elements and small in size

```
vector<vector<int> >vect{ { 11, 12 }, { 434 }, { 9, 10 } };
```