# How to overcome error int[int] in this code

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
int main() { 
    int i,j,a; 
    cin >> i >> j; // i = number of rows, j = number of queries
    int arr[i]; // defining array with i rows
    for(int k=0; k<i ; k++){

        cin >> a;

        int arr[k][a]; //defining kth row of array with a columns

        for(int l=0; l<a ; l++){
            cin >> arr[k][l]; // accepting values  
        }
    }
    for(int k=0; k<j ; k++){
        int z1,z2;
        cin >> z1 >> z2; // accepting queries
      cout << arr[z1][z2] << endl; // printing values from queries
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives me conpilation error at second loop of main.

```
Solution.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Solution.cpp:29:25: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
       cout << arr[z1][z2] << endl; // printing values from queries
```

this is the question i am trying to solve

/*
Consider an -element array, , where each index  in the array contains a reference to an array of  integers (where the value of  varies from array to array). See the Explanation section below for a diagram.

Given , you must answer  queries. Each query is in the format i j, where  denotes an index in array  and  denotes an index in the array located at . For each query, find and print the value of element  in the array at location  on a new line.

Click here to know more about how to create variable sized arrays in C++.

Input Format

The first line contains two space-separated integers denoting the respective values of  (the number of variable-length arrays) and  (the number of queries).
Each line  of the  subsequent lines contains a space-separated sequence in the format k a[i]0 a[i]1 … a[i]k-1 describing the -element array located at .
Each of the  subsequent lines contains two space-separated integers describing the respective values of  (an index in array ) and  (an index in the array referenced by ) for a query.
*/

Comment: Normal static arrays aren't really good in your case, however, that's where vectors come in. Check out this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694838/how-to-implement-2d-vector-array) for more info. Could you also provide a description of what you are trying to do? Some parts of your code doesn't make sense...

Comment: The 2D arr is going out of scope after exiting the first loop. Second loop you are now trying to access your initial array, which is only 1D.

Comment: This question was solved by using dynamic memory allocation. Thank you.