# İnner class variables into vector in outer

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Outer{
        public:
        void send_into_vector();
        vector<vector<inner>>getVector(); 
         PegSolitaire(vector<vector<inner>cvect);
        class inner{
            public:
            int get_i1();
            int get_i2();
            void set(int io,int it);
            
            private:
            int i1;
            int i2;
        };
        
    private:
    vector<vector<inner>vect;
};

int Outer :: inner :: get_i1(){
    return i1;
}

int Outer :: inner :: get_i2(){
    return i2;
}


void Outer :: inner :: set(int io,int it){
    i1=io;
    i2=it;
}

vector<vector<inner>> Outer :: getVector(){
    return vect;
}

Outer :: Outer (vector<vector<inner>cvect){
    cvect=vect;
}

void Outer :: send_into_vector(){
    vect.push_back(a.get_i1);
    vect.push_back(a.get_i2);
}
int main()
{
    Outer :: inner a;
    a.set(1,2);
    
    

    return 0;
}
```

The outer class have inner class named inner.I am trying to create a 2d vector like vector<vectorvect and ı have to used vector for put on variable in inner class.So I mean i1 and i2 values print into 2d vector on outer class private section.I am trying variable  ı get error from compiler.

Comment: I have looked at the code. There are so many things wrong in this code. Friendly advice: please check how to define member function of the class, how to access them, go through template introduction again and a quick search on google can show you how you can create 2D vector. For example, this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694838/how-to-implement-2d-vector-array

Comment: This in not important part.I write this in 30 second.İmportant part is how can I send in vector that variable in inner class using inner data type(vector<vector<inner>>vect)

Comment: It is very important. You are asking for help, and your code shows that you need to understand the basics concepts first. Go through your code again, and you will realize what I am talking about. Do you want a vector<inner> or vector<vector<inner>> as private member variable? In your code, send_into_vector() function from where 'a' comes from?

Comment: If your member variable is of type "vector<vector<inner>>" vect then you have to push a 'vector<inner>' into vect not the 'inner' type object. If you are sure that you want to use vector<vector<inner>> Then, it can be done via vect({a}) where is 'a' is type of 'inner' type.

Comment: There's a bit of a terminology issue here. C++ doesn't have "inner" and "outer" classes. The class named `inner` is a member of the class named `Outer`, and is often referred to as a **nested** class. The reason for not using "inner" and "outer" is that Java programmers think that those words have a special meaning, which they do in Java but not in C++.